# Postman GET url request test for simple server API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postman

I'm learning server-side javascript and am trying to test a GET request using postman where the server (server.js) receives a request for products.html (products.js) and returns the products JSON.

My files are packaged via npm, products.js is held in node_modules, and when I run server.js in command and then open localhost:3000 in browser, I can see that it's connecting. But, the browser returns a 404 and command shows a 400.

I feel like this is likely a syntax or file path error (or possibly I just don't know how to use postman), but I've been running myself in circles trying to fix. Anything stand out as wrong / any advice on how to correct?

```
//server.js
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var product_mgr = require('product_manager'),
path=require('path');


//create server that listens on port 3000
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var urlObj = url.parse(req.url, true, false);
    var filename = urlObj.pathname;
    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
      // if url not returned, show error code 404
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        return res.end("404 Not Found");
      } else {
      // if url returned, show success code 200
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      res.write(data);
      return res.end();
    }});
}).listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000.');
});
```

```
//products.js
//create class that represents a product
//include name, price, description and qty
class Product {
    constructor(name, price, description, qty) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.qty = qty;
    };
};

var product_1 = new Product('Yo Yo', 2.99, 'Spinning Toy', 40);
var product_2 = new Product('Hot Wheel', 1.99, 'Tiny Toy Car', 30);
var product_3 = new Product('Glove', 23.49, 'Baseball Glove', 12);
var productArray = [product_1, product_2, product_3];

//create function called products which returns JSON array of product info
function products() {
    return JSON.stringify(productArray)
};

//export products function
exports.products = products;
```

Comment: What is `require('product_manager')`? Is that a module you wrote? You're also not using it anywhere in your server code, neither are you requiring `products.js` or calling its `products` function. Provided that postman is requesting `http://localhost:3000/products.js` and `products.js` is in the same folder as `server.js`, your code *might* send the source code to the browser.

Comment: Here's fixed code: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-browser-52in4?file=/src/index.js (I'll also recommend using [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) instead)

Comment: Thanks for reviewing / responding, Chris! As it turns out, my instructor pointed out a number of items to revise within my server.js files - revised code posted for review, if anyone should come across this.

Comment: Also, per postman, I now understand it's functionality to be pretty similar to the Chrome Inspect tool / Firefox's Web Dev tools (at least in context of this simple set-up).

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var product_mgr = require('product_manager');


http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var urlObj = url.parse(req.url, true, false);
    var filename = "." + urlObj.pathname;
    if (req.method == "GET" && req.url == "/products.html") {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            error: null
        }));
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            error: "Invalid Request"
            }));
    }
}).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000.');
});
```

Comment: Hey Josh, to update your code you can edit your question. Answers should always be actual answers, not merely updates to the question.